# C# - Hide window on input from user

Tags: c#

I have put this code in my application, I want the window to hide when control + Q is clicked, why does this not work?

```
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Q)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code is needed for this? I just want to know how to do it. I don't want any tweaking in my code.

Comment: Where do you want to capture `Ctrl+Q` when the window is closed? In another application window or do you want to register it as a global shortcut?

Comment: Solutions to the question may be too broad which might lead to discussion from users and this site is not a discussion forum.. You better might have luck in other stackexchange site like programmers. In order to be more specific post your code so other might help on your code.. else try another site.

Comment: No, I want it so when the window is open, if the user inputs Ctrl+Q it will hide the window until they click CTRL+Q again.

Comment: @TFrost Programmers.SE is not a discussion forum either; over there it'd be off-topic as well as too broad.

Comment: @lxrec : sorry my mad.. I meant to say meta...

Comment: Is `Form1_KeyDown` registered as a KeyDown event on Form1?

Comment: @FlyingFoX no it is not. How do I do that? Sorry I'm a newbie!

Comment: I assume that you are using Windows Forms and Visual Studio. To check if your method is registered as an event open Form1 in the designer, go to properties, click on the event tab and look for the KeyDown event. If everything is fine you should see `Form1_KeyDown` there.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Key modifier in order to handle Keys combination

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Q && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
  {
    //do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. The program still doesn't do anything when I hit control + Q

Comment: @RaghavJ. try to messagebox the key pressed first.